# How do I order data once only for all controllers?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I'm writing a very simple app in CakePHP 3 (3.0.13) and I'd like to know if I can do something simple, better.

I'm essentially writing an issue tracker to keep on top of issues and jobs. I have a table called priorities containing a unique ID and name for each level, say Low, Medium and High. My issue is that while I have added these to the database in the order I would like them to appear, they are appearing in alphabetical order, so High, Low, Medium.

In my Issue controller's add function (for example) I can change the following:

`$priorities = $this->Issues->Priorities->find('list');`

...to:

`$priorities = $this->Issues->Priorities->find('list', ['order' => 'Priorities.id ASC']);`

...but I don't want to have to do this everywhere I want to use the list of priorities.

I imagine there is a DRY way of specifying this (in the model?) which effectively sets the default for use everywhere else, but if there is, I cannot find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could overwrite `Table::findList()` in your `PrioritiesTable` class, and add your order conditions to the query, something like

```
public function findList(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query = parent::findList($query, $options);
    return $query->order(['Priorities.id' => 'ASC']);
}
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::findList()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_findList)**